# ggplot plotly API mess width stack bar graph

Tags: ggplot2, plotly

I am using plotly library to get me HTML interactive graph, which i already generating from ggplot2, but with stacked graph, plotly doesnt work properly.

Here is my ggplot code :

```
if(file.exists(filename)) {
  data = read.table(filename,sep=",",header=T)
} else {
  g <- paste0("=== [E] Error : Couldn't Found File : ",filename)
  print (g)
}
  ReadChData <- data[data$Channel %in% c("R"),]
  #head(ReadChData,10)

# calculate midpoints of bars (simplified using comment by @DWin)
Data <- ddply(ReadChData, .(qos_level), 
   transform, pos = cumsum(AvgBandwidth) - (0.5 *AvgBandwidth)
)

# library(dplyr) ## If using dplyr... 
# Data <- group_by(Data,Year) %>%
#    mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))

# plot bars and add text
g <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = qos_level, y = AvgBandwidth)) +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_axis_break) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = MasterID), stat="identity", width=0.2) +
     scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7)) +
     geom_text(aes(label = AvgBandwidth, y = pos), size = 3) +
     theme_set(theme_bw()) +
     ylab("Bandwidth (GB/s)") +
     xlab("QoS Level") +
     ggtitle("Qos Compting Stream")

png(paste0(opt$out,"/",GraphName,".png"),width=6*ppi, height=6*ppi, res=ppi)
print (g)

library(plotly)
p <- ggplotly(g)
#libdir arugumet will be use to point to commin lib
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), selfcontained=FALSE, paste0(opt$out,"/qos_competing_stream.html"))
```

and here is HTML output form plotly lib

http://pasteboard.co/2fHQfJwFu.jpg

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perhaps quite a bit late to answer. But for someone who might have the issue in future...

The `geom_bar`'s width parameter is not recognized by `ggplotly` function.

1. Work Around :
   A work around (not very good one) by using parameters `colour="white", size = 1`. This basically adds a white line around the bars, making an effect like white space. 
   You could try the following:
   `stat_summary(aes(fill = MasterID), geom="bar", colour="white", size = 1, fun.y = "sum", position = "stack")`
2. Better solution : 
   Use `bargap` parameter from `layout` function. The code should be:
   `ggplotly(type='bar', ...) %>% layout(bargap = 3, autosize=T)`

P.S. the code in question code is not executable, throws an error due to missing filename.

Comment: thanks. I started to use plotly javascript in offiline mode instead of generating from ggplot object. however will accept the answer.